# What SQL magic do I need to turn one column into several?

Tags: sql, relational-database

I need to print some tickets, each of which has enough room to hold one set of customer details along with codes for up to five items ordered by that customer. Customers who have ordered more than five items get multiple tickets. So from an orders table like this,

```
Customer | Item
---------|------
Bob      | FTMCH
Bob      | ZORP
Bob      | KLUGE
Carol    | FTMCH
Carol    | MEEP
Carol    | ZORP
Ted      | FOON
Ted      | SMOCK
Alice    | ORGO
Carol    | SQICK
Carol    | BLECH
Carol    | KLUGE
Carol    | GLURP
```

I need a query that returns this:

```
Customer | Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 | Item5
---------|-------|-------|-------|-------|------
Alice    | ORGO  | null  | null  | null  | null
Bob      | FTMCH | ZORP  | KLUGE | null  | null
Carol    | FTMCH | MEEP  | ZORP  | SQICK | BLECH
Carol    | KLUGE | GLURP | null  | null  | null
Ted      | FOON  | SMOCK | null  | null  | null
```

Can some kind soul help me with the SQL for this? HSQL embedded database in OpenOffice.org Base, if it makes a difference.

Comment: Is there an upper limit to the number of Items or is it variable?

Comment: There is no upper limit to the number of items per customer that may occur in the orders table. There are always exactly five ItemN columns required in the query result. The orders table can be assumed to contain no nulls. If the orders table contains M rows for any given customer, the query result should contain floor((M+4)/5) rows for that customer, at most one of which may contain nulls. Item1 should always be non-null; if ItemN is null, so should ItemN+1 through Item5 be.

Comment: I am quite enamored with your pseudo data values, BTW. Have you ever thought of writing a programming book for kids a la Dr. Seuss?

Comment: Roger Kaufman has that territory pretty well staked out already :-) 
http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~kaufman1/FortranColoringBook/ColoringBkCover.html

Answer (score 2):

OK, this works well enough:

```
SELECT
    "Customer",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Slot" = 0 THEN "Item" END) AS "Item1",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Slot" = 1 THEN "Item" END) AS "Item2",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Slot" = 2 THEN "Item" END) AS "Item3",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Slot" = 3 THEN "Item" END) AS "Item4",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Slot" = 4 THEN "Item" END) AS "Item5"
FROM (
    SELECT
        l."Customer" AS "Customer",
        l."Item" AS "Item",
        COUNT(r."Item") / 5 AS "Ticket",
        MOD(COUNT(r."Item"), 5) AS "Slot"
    FROM "Orders" AS l
    LEFT JOIN "Orders" AS r
    ON r."Customer" = l."Customer" AND r."Item" < l."Item"
    GROUP BY "Customer", "Item"
)
GROUP BY "Customer", "Ticket"
ORDER BY "Customer", "Ticket"
```

It makes this:

```
Customer | Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 | Item5 
---------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------
Alice    | ORGO  |       |       |       |       
Bob      | FTMCH | KLUGE | ZORP  |       |       
Carol    | BLECH | FTMCH | GLURP | KLUGE | MEEP  
Carol    | SQICK | ZORP  |       |       |       
Ted      | FOON  | SMOCK |       |       |
```

Thanks to all who helped, both here and at [Ask Metafilter.](http://ask.metafilter.com/173549/I-havent-needed-SQL-this-ugly-before)

(Followup edit:)

Jesus, this just gets worse :-(

Turns out the business rules allow the same customer to order the same item on multiple occasions, and that all outstanding orders are to be included on the one set of tickets. So my toy table should have looked more like this:

```
ID  | Customer | Item 
159 | Bob      | FTMCH
264 | Bob      | ZORP 
265 | Bob      | KLUGE
288 | Carol    | FTMCH
314 | Carol    | MEEP 
323 | Carol    | ZORP 
327 | Ted      | FOON 
338 | Ted      | SMOCK
358 | Alice    | ORGO 
419 | Carol    | SQICK
716 | Carol    | MEEP 
846 | Carol    | BLECH
939 | Carol    | MEEP 
950 | Carol    | GLURP
979 | Carol    | KLUGE
```

Carol's multiple MEEPs bugger the ranking logic in the original solution, and I've ended up with the following hideous monster:

```
SELECT
    "Customer",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Slot" = 0 THEN "Item" END) AS "Item0",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Slot" = 1 THEN "Item" END) AS "Item1",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Slot" = 2 THEN "Item" END) AS "Item2",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Slot" = 3 THEN "Item" END) AS "Item3",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Slot" = 4 THEN "Item" END) AS "Item4",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Slot" = 0 THEN "Quantity" END) AS "Qty0",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Slot" = 1 THEN "Quantity" END) AS "Qty1",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Slot" = 2 THEN "Quantity" END) AS "Qty2",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Slot" = 3 THEN "Quantity" END) AS "Qty3",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Slot" = 4 THEN "Quantity" END) AS "Qty4"
FROM (
    SELECT
        "Customer",
        "Item",
        COUNT("ID") AS "Quantity",
        "Rank" / 5 AS "Ticket",
        MOD("Rank", 5) AS "Slot"
    FROM (
        SELECT
            main."ID" AS "ID",
            main."Customer" AS "Customer",
            main."Item" AS "Item",
            COUNT(less."Item") AS "Rank"
        FROM "Orders" AS main
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                "Customer",
                "Item"
            FROM "Orders") AS less
        ON less."Customer" = main."Customer" AND less."Item" < main."Item"
        GROUP BY "ID", "Customer", "Item"
    )
    GROUP BY "Customer", "Item", "Rank"
)
GROUP BY "Customer", "Ticket"
```

which makes this:

```
Customer | Item0 | Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 | Qty0 | Qty1 | Qty2 | Qty3 | Qty3 | Qty4
Bob      | FTMCH | KLUGE | ZORP  |       |       | 1    | 1    | 1    |      |      |     
Carol    | BLECH | FTMCH | GLURP | KLUGE | MEEP  | 1    | 1    | 1    | 1    | 1    | 3   
Carol    | SQICK | ZORP  |       |       |       | 1    | 1    |      |      |      |     
Ted      | FOON  | SMOCK |       |       |       | 1    | 1    |      |      |      |     
Alice    | ORGO  |       |       |       |       | 1    |      |      |      |      |
```

It does the job, I guess, but I'm feeling pretty lucky that the database involved is always going to be quite small (a few thousand rows).

Spiritually I'm an embedded-systems guy, not a database guy. Can anybody who does this for a living tell me whether this kind of nonsense is common? Would a query with four nested SELECTs and a LEFT JOIN merit a mention on the Daily WTF?

Comment: Yeah, this is gross. IMHO this kind of formatting doesn't belong in a SQL query at all, but rather the application retrieving the data should do it. If this was driving a web page to be rendered by PHP, for example, I'd definitely say it was TDWTF material. I'm guessing from your requirements that the SQL query is the only data transformation opportunity you've got though, in which case "needs must".

Comment: Thanks; I suspected that might be the case. In fact this was a stopgap measure needed only until I finish the new front end I'm currently working on, which uses *sensible* queries.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is only usable for T-SQL, but you can use PIVOT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

I did something similar with a list of dates becoming the columns for calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked, and MySQL rather than OpenOffice, but might give you an idea or someone else could work on it :

```
select
    u.Customer,
    group_concat(u.Item) items
from
    (select
        t.Item,
        @n:=if(@c=t.Customer and @n<4,@n+1,0) c1,
        @m:=if(@n,@m,@m+1) g,
        @c:=t.Customer as Customer
    from
        t1 t, (select @m:=0) init
    order
        by t.Customer
    ) u
group by
    u.g
```

Output :

```
+----------+------------------------------+
| Customer | items                        |
+----------+------------------------------+
| Alice    | ORGO                         | 
| Bob      | FTMCH,ZORP,KLUGE             | 
| Carol    | KLUGE,ZORP,BLECH,SQICK,GLURP | 
| Carol    | MEEP,FTMCH                   | 
| Ted      | FOON,SMOCK                   | 
+----------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: HSQL doesn't seem to have user-defined variables, so I'd need some other way to number the rows. Will play with this and get back to you.

Comment: Concatenating produces one column instead of five. And uses a non-standard Function.

Answer (score 0):

This gets you most of the way there, but does not handle the duplicate order for `Carol`. That would be easy to do if there was something else to group on, like `OrderID` or `OrderDate`. Can you post the full schema?

```
select m1.Customer, 
    min(m1.Item) as Item1, 
    min(m2.item) as Item2, 
    min(m3.item) as Item3, 
    min(m4.item) as Item4, 
    min(m5.item) as Item5
from CustomerOrder m1
left outer join CustomerOrder m2 on m1.Customer = m2.Customer 
    and m2.item > m1.item
left outer join CustomerOrder m3 on m1.Customer = m3.Customer 
    and m3.item > m2.item
left outer join CustomerOrder m4 on m1.Customer = m4.Customer 
    and m4.item > m3.item
left outer join CustomerOrder m5 on m1.Customer = m5.Customer 
    and m5.item > m4.item
group by m1.Customer
```

**Output:**

```
Customer       Item1      Item2      Item3      Item4      Item5
-------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Alice          ORGO       NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL
Bob            FTMCH      KLUGE      ZORP       NULL       NULL
Carol          BLECH      FTMCH      GLURP      KLUGE      MEEP
Ted            FOON       SMOCK      NULL       NULL       NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is not uncommon, and can be supplied reasonably in SQL.  But you have two issues blocking you.

1) You've entered an SQL tag, that means ISO/IEC/ANSI Standard SQL. The correct method to use is a cursor or cursor substitute (while loop, which does the same thing, but is faster).  That avoids all these outer joins and handling massive result sets; then beating it into submission with GROUP BYs, etc.  It also handles duplicates, mainly because it does it create them in the first place (via those five versions of the aliased table).  And yes, it will keep getting worse, and when the database is reasonably populated it will be a performance hog.

2) Duplicates are not allowed in a Relational database, ie. in your source tables; you need to make the rows unique (and those keys/columns is not shown).  No use trying to eliminate duplicates via code.  If that is corrected, then *all* duplicates (real and created by the poor code) can be eliminated.

This requirement can also be supplied more elegantly using Subqueries; except that here you need two levels of nesting, one to build teach Item column, and two to obtain rank or Position.  And that (standard SQL construct) pre-supposes that you have a Relational database (no duplicate rows).  High Eek factor if you are not used to SQL. Which is why most coders use a cursor or cursor substitute.

But if you do not have SQL, its basic capabilities, (HSQL being some sub-standard implementation), then we are not using the same tool kit.  The SQL code I can provide will not run for you, and we will keep going back and forth.

(Maybe we should have a "psuedo-SQL" tag.)

**`ID` Column Prevents Duplicates ???**

There is a myth that is prevalent in some parts of the industry, to that effect, due to books written by database beginners. As usual, myths have no scientific basis.  Let's try a simple test.

```
    CREATE TABLE Person (
    PersonId  IDENTITY NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    LastName  CHAR(30) NOT NULL
    )

    INSERT Person VALUES ("Fred", "Astaire")
1 row(s) affected

    INSERT Person VALUES ("Ginger", "Rogers")
1 row(s) affected

    INSERT Person VALUES ("Fred", "Astaire")
1 row(s) affected

    SELECT * FROM Person

PersonId FirstName                      LastName
======== ============================== ==============================
       1 Fred                           Astaire
       2 Ginger                         Rogers
       3 Fred                           Astaire

3 row(s) affected
```

That's a pure, unarguable duplicate row.  The simple fact is. the `Id` column provides a row number, but does nothing to prevent duplicate rows.  For that you need an **Unique** Index on the columns that determine uniqueness, as identified in the data model, for every relational table in the database (by definition, if the rows are not unique, it is not a Relational table).  Otherwise it is just a file storage system.

```
    CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX U_Name
       ON Person (LastName, FirstName)
```

There is another form of data integrity (duplication) which I might identify while I am at it.

```
    INSERT Person VALUES ("Fred", "Astair")
1 row(s) affected

    INSERT Person VALUES ("Astaire", "Fred")
1 row(s) affected
```

All are preventable in SQL.

Comment: I don't yet have the SQL chops to understand your points about cursors and subqueries. But none of the sample tables I supplied do in fact contain duplicates; the Orders table in the extended solution for the case where multiple orders are allowed has an ID column to prevent them.

Comment: @flabdablet.  1) Can you explain how an `ID` columns prevents duplicates. 2) if you post your full table DDL (all indices), I can post the subquery required.